# I cannot git clone ssh protocal repository after add id_rsa.pub key to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

it seems to work fine on windows 
but does not work on Linux
it's strange

"
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
"

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a separate ssh key for Linux.

After you add the public key to git, you need to get the ssh link to the repo.

Then inside the repo, from your terminal do:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:RepoName/project
```

after this do:

```
git remote -v
```

in order to check if you are using ssh now.

now do:

```
git pull
```

and everything should be working correctly.